# 1004 error for vba script

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that I merged with another code. On their own both codes work fine, but now I encounter a 1004 runtime error and I cant figure out why It gives a 1004 error for the second to last line "Set = Varrange ..."

```
Sub Simulate500k()

Dim i As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim ROI As Integer
Dim Nummer As Integer
Dim NBC As Integer
Dim Spalte As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim nblock As Integer




Nummer = Worksheets("Control").Cells(10, 2).Value
ROI = Worksheets("Control").Cells(9, 3).Value
NBC = Worksheets("Control").Cells(10, 5).Value
Spalte = Worksheets("Control").Cells(7, 5).Value
n = Worksheets("Control").Cells(11, 5).Value
nblock = Worksheets("Control").Cells(12, 5).Value


For k = nblock To 260

Worksheets("table").Cells(ROI * 17 + 1, 4 + 12 * NBC).Copy
Worksheets("Control").Cells(15, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Worksheets("table").Cells(ROI * 17 + 1, 6 + 12 * NBC).Copy
Worksheets("Control").Cells(6, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

For m = 1 To 14

 For i = 4 To 103

  Worksheets("500k").Cells(5, 2).Copy
  Worksheets("500k").Cells(2, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

  Set varRangeselect1 = Worksheets("500k").Range(Cells(6, 2), Cells(106, 2))
  Set varRangeSelect2 = Worksheets("500k").Range(Cells(6, i), Cells(106, i))
  varRangeselect1.Copy
  varRangeSelect2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: I don't see where you declare the `varRangeSelect2` variable. Are you sure you declared it as a range variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign parentage to all Range Objects including the `Cells()` inside the `Range()`.  The easiest is with a `With` block:

```
With Worksheets("500k")
    Set varRangeselect1 = .Range(.Cells(6, 2), .Cells(106, 2))
    Set varRangeSelect2 = .Range(.Cells(6, i), .Cells(106, i))
End with
```

So inside the `With` block anything that starts with `.` is assigned to the parentage stated in the `With` statement.

Comment: @IschaIschratioh I am glad.  Please come back in a few minutes and mark it as correct.